# What should I do when my question is downvoted (and has a negative score)?

Tags: support, questions

What is the proper way to deal with my own question when it is downvoted, and has -2 votes?

**Should I delete my question? Do nothing? Something else?**

A commenter said one of my questions ([How do I force VM to pause/suspend when host is put to sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46839262/3384936)) was not appropriate for Stack Overflow because it was not a *programming* question. Although it was asked to indirectly help me with a programming issue, i.e., so I could run my IDE, they have a point.

Note that one answer was offered, but I didn’t mark it as being the answer.

Also, I reposted my question to a separate SO site, which was also suggested by the same commenter.

Comment: this question in particular there is nothing you can do other than get it migrated or delete it.

Comment: I look elsewhere for a solution and if/when I eventually find one, I go back to my question and answer it so future Internet searchers can find it. I still get random points for answering things years ago. I'm of the opinion that some people on this network look down upon others if they deem questions stupid. Don't let it get you down.

Answer (score 25):

If you've already reposted your question on another Stack Exchange site, and you don't feel it belongs on Stack Overflow, and it's closed with a score of -2, then deleting it is *absolutely* correct. It serves no useful purpose here.

Alternatively, it will be [roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) in a little over a week.

Comment: As a side note: the post will be counted for question ban and there pretty much nothing you can do to recover completely off-topic question. If question ban is of any consideration I'd be cautious to delete question with an answer myself and probably let Roomba delete it (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th - "deletion itself counts against questions if less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the OP probably doesn't need to worry about a question ban; they've got (as far as I can see) a pretty decent record.

Comment: The question isn’t *closed*, but it is *on hold.* Same difference?

Comment: @EJMak "on hold" pretty much just means "closed recently".

Comment: _Roomba'd_? What is that word supposed to mean? I liked the sound of that though.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ [roomba meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year). And I think roomba will only eat that Q&A if the score of the answer stays <=0.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba. It's just an automatic vacuum cleaner and the word has come to mean "getting rid of stuff", often autonomously.